# How do I make every vertex to be associated with the same number of bones?

Tags: bones

If I want to make every vertex to be associated with three joints, no more or less, is there a way that doesn't involve manually setting the vertex?

Answer (score 1):

There is an operator called **Limit Number of Weights per Vertex**:

> Limit deform weights associated with a vertex to a specified number by removing lowest weights

Operator call in Python:

```
bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_limit_total(group_select_mode='ALL', limit=4)
```

You can find it while in *Edit Mode* of the parented mesh,
in the 3D View <kbd>T</kbd>-toolshelf *> Tools > Weight Tools > Limit Total*.

Or you go to *Weight Paint* mode *> Weights menu > Limit Total*.

Comment: Does this operator make the same lowest and max number of bones to associate with each vertex? If I set the Limit Total to 3, all the vertices will have at least three weights and bones, but not more than that?

Comment: If a vertex has a weight of `0.8` for *Bone*, `0.5` for *Bone.001*, `0.3` for *Bone.002* and `0.2` for *Bone.003* and you run the operator with a **limit of 3**, the vertex will be removed from group *Bone.003* (so no weight anymore).

Comment: Is there a way to make the vertices have at least a certain number of bones to be associated with, not only the max number they can have?

Comment: No, like the name suggests, it **limits** the maximum number but does not enforce it - it's impossible. How would it be supposed to assign vertices to groups? Randomly? Based on proximity? There's no clear solution.